# Ungracefully terminating pods

Tags: kubernetes, testing

To test that the high-availability mode does what it should, I need to kill the instances during testing, and I need to kill them in such way that they can't report they are disconnecting or similar.

For practical reasons I need to do the testing on smaller environment that does not have a separate node for each pod, so I can't test by turning off the machines, but need to kill the processes instead. I can kill them with `docker kill`, but that requires logging into the node and finding the docker id of the container. Is there some way to achieve similar effect via `exec kill`, but sending `SIGKILL` to process ID 1 is not allowed.

I also see delete being used, but I have some case where there is a difference: when deleting, the container is recreated with clean state, but merely restarting it does not and the deployment I am testing actually looks at the state during start-up and has problem starting up, so I need to test the case where it is not deleted.

Can I forcibly terminate pods without giving them any chance for cleaning up via the kubernetes API/`kubectl`?

Answer (score 7):

You can try to use command

```
kubectl delete pods <pod> --grace-period=0 --force
```

The key `--grace-period=<seconds>` is time, which Kubernetes waits for graceful shutdown of a Pod. If it is 0, SIGKILL will be sent immediately to any process in the Pod. The key `--force` must be specified for such kind of operation in versions of Kubernetes 1.5 and higher.

For more information, you can check the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#termination-of-pods).

Comment: Note that the question explicitly states `delete` is *not* appropriate for the purpose. There is a functionally significant difference between the pod being deleted and the process in the container dying.

Comment: Yep, but seems there is no other opportunity

Comment: If there seems to be no other opportunity, then the solution is to implement it, not using something that does not do the right thing.